# MongoDB - How to select data that has a field equals to the minimum field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB and I want to select **all users** having the **minimum age**.
Something like this:

```
db.users.find({age: {$min: age}})
```

Seems really basic but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: You have to write an Aggregation query for that. To start with see [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/min/index.html).

Comment: @turivishal let's say I have 4 users with ages 22, 35, 41, 22. I want the 2 users with age 22.

Comment: What I understand is a very simple query where you get documents which `age` field is greater than a number. Check if [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zPxVVmnDRk1) is what you expect. Also edit your question an add a document example and expected output.

Comment: @J.F. this is not what I expect, sorry my question wasn't clear enough. turivishal's answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$gorup` by `age` and make array of `users`
- `$sort` by `_id` means `age` in ascending order
- `$limit` 1 document

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$age",
      users: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PQtawytS5ML)

Comment: Works fine thanks! I do not understand everything but I will investigate 